# Working on multiple projects with IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

Currently, in our team we have few projects each for individual on-line service. We also have multiple projects each creating a library of its own that are used by the service projects. So we have something like

- project: `library-fetch-data`  - A library to fetch data
- project: `library-transform-data`  - A library to transform data
- project: `library-authenticate-user`  - A library to authenticate a user
  etc..
- project: `service-x`  - A service to serve data  requires: library-fetch-data, library-transform-data
- project: `service-y`  - A service to authenticate user  requires: library-fetch-data, library-authenticate-user
  etc..

Now, while working with intellij, when I open a project say `library-fetch-data` and ask for the usage of a function it only returns the usage of the function in project `library-fetch-data`. What I am looking for is something that would give the usage of the function in project `service-x` as well (since project `service-x` uses `library-fetch-data`). One solution could be to convert all projects into a sub-projects of a single project but is not possible since these projects span multiple teams (even multiple business units)

- Is it, then, possible to create a Intellij configuration files that span across multiple projects, since I have access to the source code of all the projects? or alternatively, it is possible to combine/merge the intellij files (*.iml, *.ipr) for multiple projects into single file?
- If not, is there any other tool can help me do analysis across projects, i.e.,. find usage of a function across all projects, find all sub classes of a class across all projects, etc.

Comment: Does `File > New > Module From Existing Sources` not do what you want? You can open multiple iml in one project

Comment: Actually, I am looking for something that I can do from command line or via the gradle ```idea``` plugin since there are many hundreds of projects involved.

Comment: I don't think Gradle will help because that is a build tool for modules that are already contained within a project.